# Hibernate: Conditional One To One mapping

Tags: hibernate, eclipselink, moxy

I am saving a XML to database with the help of JAXB and Hibernate. There are two elements at the same level

```
<ElementA id="111-aa>
 <childern/>
</ElementA>

<Relation refId=111-aa">
 <childern/>
</Relation>
```

Here if `ElementA/@id==Relation/@refId` only then I have to save ElementA's PK to Relation table's ElementA_FK column.

> Note: I am using EclipseLink's MOXy to read attribute from elements.

Does Hibernate provide one-to-one mapping based on a condition?

Note